# I'm getting credential errors on my newly installed GridDB instances. I've changed the password but it doesn't change anything

Tags: database, nosql, iot, in-memory-database, griddb

This seems like an odd error to bring up because generally it's 100% due to user error, but there's just no way at this point. The error is definitely occurring on the GridDB side.

I have installed and set up 3 separate nodes of GridDB on Azure. Setting the password works:

```
[root@node2 gridstore]# gs_passwd admin
Password: 
Retype password:
```

But when I get in there to join my cluster I get errors:

```
[root@node2 gridstore]# su gsadm
bash-4.2$ /usr/bin/gs_startnode 
bash-4.2$ /usr/bin/gs_joincluster -c <cluster_name> -u \
> admin/<my_password>
A00102: Authentication error occurred.
Confirm user name and password.
```

I've tried going back and changing the password to something generic (password) just to make sure it works:

```
[root@node2 gridstore]# gs_passwd admin
Password: "password"
Retype password: "password"
```

but I continue to get the same error:

```
[root@node2 gridstore]# su gsadm
bash-4.2$ /usr/bin/gs_startnode 
AD0102: gsserver process may exist.
PID is 88153
bash-4.2$ /usr/bin/gs_joincluster -c <cluster_name> -u \
> admin/password
A00102: Authentication error occurred.
Confirm user name and password.
```

Since I know for sure the password is now "password" (I've changed it multiple times at this point), shouldn't it be connecting me by now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your original password contain any special characters? GridDB currently doesn’t accept passwords with chars like %, etc.

As for changing your password and still not working — did you stop the node (gs_stop node) before changing the pass? The changes won’t stick if you do it while the node is running.

Comment: That was it -- I needed to stop the node, change the PW to a one with regular characters and then it worked. Thanks!